# EDMX Designer like in c# at runtime

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, designer, gui-designer

I need a designer tool to use in my application to allow the user to design a database model.

Are there any designer tools that can be integrated and utilized using C# code at runtime?

I guess WF designer may be useful, but I couldn't find any examples of how to use it as entity designer or database designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to customize the WF designer to get the desired designer.
I think this may be useful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa480213

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at: [Visual Studio Visualization and Modeling SDK](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk). You find all resource for create a customized graphic designer.

Comment: Thanks @Felice, from the first look I think it's what i need, but can it be used in a seperated C# project, or it can be used only to extend Visual Studio Architecture tools?

Comment: @MSS AFAIK it is not possible, it could be used only in Visual Studio, but there is a special visual studio version you can deploy to customer, look for "Visual Studio Shell" on the web.